# Combine 3 data object into a single data object within Vue template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

OK, so this is the high level. I have 3 objects under a data() field

```
data () {
   birth_day: '',
   birth_month: '',
   birth_year: '',
   birthdate: '',
}
```

I also have a 4th data object called birthdate as you can see above. When a user fills in each item, I want to combine them into birthdate in the format YEAR-MONTH-DAY (for Database storage)

I also, if possible, want to add a 0 if someone types say 3 for March and not 03

I am having an issue wrapping my head around this. This is part of a multi-step registration form.

Any help would be very helpful!

PS for anyone asking - this is the template code:

```
<div class="flex flex-row justify-between">
                    
   <div class="relative border border-gray-500 rounded-md px-3 py-2 shadow-sm focus-within:ring-1 focus-within:ring-red-600 focus-within:border-red-600">
       <label for="birth_month" value="birth_month" class="absolute -top-2 left-2 -mt-px inline-block px-1 bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-50">Month</label>
       <input minlength="2" maxlength="2" type="text" name="birth_month" id="birth_month" class="bg-gray-900 text-white block w-full border-0 p-0 placeholder-gray-500 focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm" placeholder="02" />
   </div>

   <div class="relative border border-gray-500 rounded-md px-3 py-2 mx-4 shadow-sm focus-within:ring-1 focus-within:ring-red-600 focus-within:border-red-600">
       <label for="birth_day" value="birth_day" class="absolute -top-2 left-2 -mt-px inline-block px-1 bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-50">Day</label>
       <input minlength="2" maxlength="2" type="text" name="birth_day" id="birth_day" class="bg-gray-900 text-white block w-full border-0 p-0 placeholder-gray-500 focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm" placeholder="15" />
   </div>

   <div class="relative border border-gray-500 rounded-md px-3 py-2 shadow-sm focus-within:ring-1 focus-within:ring-red-600 focus-within:border-red-600">
      <label for="birth_year" value="birth_year" class="absolute -top-2 left-2 -mt-px inline-block px-1 bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-50">Year</label>
      <input minlength="4" maxlength="4" type="text" name="birth_year" id="birth_year" class="bg-gray-900 text-white block w-full border-0 p-0 placeholder-gray-500 focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm" placeholder="2000" />
   </div> 

</div>
```

Comment: For `birthdate`, you should probably use something like `date-fns` to properly handle this. Otherwise, a computed property should be enough to mix all those 3 together.

Comment: If I was doing date manipulation I would agree, but all I need to do is combine them into the right order and store it accordingly, Yes, there will be some error control (such as nobody under 18) but this isn't the issue here. I just cannot remember the best way to combine this all into a single data object

Comment: How should the code respond if the day, month, year entered is 29, 02, 1999? Should it store `birthdate` as '1999-02-29`? _NOTE: 1999 is not a leap year and hence February does not have 29 days_.

Comment: @jsN00b see thats a very valid statement. That is something I am struggling with. I wanted initially to use a date picker but I was just not happy with what I was finding at the time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      birth_day: '',
      birth_month: '',
      birth_year: '',
      birthdate: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    formatNr(nr) {
      if(this[nr].length < 2) this[nr] = `0${this[nr]}`
    },
    formatDate() {
      return `${this.birth_year}-${this.birth_month}-${this.birth_day}`
    },
    save() {
      this.birthdate = this.formatDate()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div>          
    <div>
      <label for="birth_month" value="birth_month">Month</label>
      <input v-model="birth_month" @blur="formatNr('birth_month'), save()" minlength="2" maxlength="2" type="text" name="birth_month" id="birth_month" placeholder="02" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="birth_day" value="birth_day">Day</label>
      <input v-model="birth_day" @blur="formatNr('birth_day'), save()" minlength="2" maxlength="2" type="text" name="birth_day" id="birth_day" placeholder="15" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="birth_year" value="birth_year">Year</label>
      <input v-model="birth_year" @blur="save()" minlength="4" maxlength="4" type="text" name="birth_year" id="birth_year" placeholder="2000" />
    </div> 
  </div>
  <h4>birthdate: {{ birthdate }}</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: 2 things
1. This is CLOSE to what I need. There is an issue (I thought of after) if someone types a 2 digit year (Which I can solve instantly now)
and 
2. I didn't want it as part of a button. I wanted it calculated when the user clicks next on the form. 
That being said, Seeing your code does give me enough of what I need to continue resolving this. If you happen to have a solution to the above 2 issues, by all means let me know!!!

Comment: @ArcticMediaRyan hey mate, you have computed property to show you your date while typing, and what is next on the form? button or some other input field? you can call `formatDate` method when ever you want :)